# Access VST-Plugin through C#

Tags: c#, plugins, vst

I'm trying to implement WaveArts Panorama 5 in a C#-Project!
I already know that there is a `VSTPluginMain()` function available, but now I want to find out how to change parameters and also how to create a correct audio output along with the specific parameters!

Is there a specific function to call, which show whats available within this plugin?

Kind regards!

Comment: Did you see this project? http://vstnet.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use either the [VST .NET](http://vstnet.codeplex.com/) or [noisevst](http://code.google.com/p/noisevst/) frameworks.